# While cloning from git i get: perl: warning: Setting locale failed

Tags: c++, git, perl, encoding, github

My OS is Linux Ubuntu Desktop 16.04. I used this command to clone files from git server:

```
$ git clone basecamp:some_acount
```

and getting this warning:

```
Cloning into 'some_acount'...
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_PAPER = "uk_UA.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "uk_UA.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "uk_UA.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "uk_UA.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "uk_UA.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "uk_UA.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "uk_UA.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "uk_UA.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "uk_UA.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
remote: Counting objects: 13, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
remote: Total 13 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (13/13), 7.73 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

I have two questions:

1. Will I have a problem with my files (static c++ libraries with
   extension ".a")?
2. How can I fix this warning?

Comment: run `sudo locale-gen uk_UA.UTF-8` and see if that fixes it

Comment: @Zanna, no. It didn't

Answer (score 1):

This should not affect the checkout. It is mainly a warning. I get something similar when logging into a linux PC from my Mac. Annoying, but not harmful.